# Git - How to Get Version of Code From Few Months Ago

Tags: git, teamcity

I am new to using git and I am trying to find out how do I revert my code to the version of code from few months ago.  So, I am providing pictures and info to help explain.

Looking at our TeamCity repository like shown below, I see that on Jan 03, 2017 @ 9:59AM, 15 files have changed:

[image]

If I expand the Changes column for that date, I can drill further down and I can see that 2 files have changed on December 30th, 2016 @9:53AM as shown below:

[image]

What is the command I need to issue in git to:

a) get my local code back in time to the version from December 30, 2016 @ 09:53AM like shown above?

b) once I am done investigating it here, how to update my code back to the current version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hexadecimal number between the number of files changed and the date in your last picture is an abbreviation of the commit ID. In your highlighted row, it’s `a145dcbc9918`.

To switch to this commit, you can run

```
git checkout a145dcbc9918
```

The same command, with the branch name of either `development` or `master` (depending on how your local repository is configured), will get you back to the top of that branch.

Comment: Cool, so I guess I could name the checkout as well?  How?  And what about my 2nd question (b)?  Much appreciated

Comment: You can use `git tag` to name an old commit (run `git help tag` for the exact options it supports). I answered your part (b) above, right below the command I gave.

Comment: Much appreciated Daniel

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
git log --since='last month' --pretty=format:'%h,%an,%ar,%s'
```

then

```
git checkout Commit_hashcode
```

you can even give it a date like

```
git log --since="2017-02-12T16:36:00-07:00"
```

there is also --before and --after check this advanced tuts:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log

Comment: Thanks but I dont need to look at git log since I should have what I need from the screenshots provided in my question right.  So, I guess my question is what is commit_hashcode in your git checkout?  Is that the string "a145dcbc9918" in red square in my last screenshot?

Comment: yes it is, you will need to checkout your repo to that date\hashcode_commit and then create a new branch from where you are standing "in the repo history" to be able to work and commit changes or deploy the new branch to prod.